# Custom css in radio button not working showing checkbox instead of radio button

Tags: css, radio-button

I try to follow some coding tutorial and try to create custom css in radio button but it is giving me square instead of circle and I can't figure it out why thanks in advance. I have tried to give class and everything but still does not work.

My Html

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio] + label:before {
    content: "\2714";
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  border-radius: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  padding-left: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
}

input[type=radio] + label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #662D91;
  border-color: #662D91;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type=radio]:disabled + label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #aaa;
}

input[type=radio]:checked:disabled + label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #bfb;
}
```

```html
<span class="oneChoice">
  <input type="radio" value="tfa_79" class="" id="tfa_79" name="tfa_78">
  <label class="label postField" id="tfa_79-L" for="tfa_79">
  <span class="input-radio-faux"></span>Patient</label>
</span> 
<span class="oneChoice">
  <input type="radio" value="tfa_79" class="" id="tfa_79" name="tfa_78">
  <label class="label postField" id="tfa_79-L" for="tfa_79">
  <span class="input-radio-faux"></span>Patient</label>
</span>
```

Comment: please also add your html code...

Comment: Updated can you check please @MinalChauhan

Comment: You added some id in both radio button, so change in input and label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added some **id** in both radio button, so change in input and label

```css
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio] + label:before {
  content: "\2714";
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  /*padding-left: 0.2em;
  padding-bottom: 0.3em;*/
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.5em;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

input[type=radio] + label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #662D91;
  border-color: #662D91;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type=radio]:disabled + label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #aaa;
}

input[type=radio]:checked:disabled + label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #bfb;
}
```

```html
<span class="oneChoice">
  <input type="radio" value="tfa_79" class="" id="tfa_79" name="tfa_78">
  <label class="label postField" id="tfa_79" for="tfa_79">
  <span class="input-radio-faux"></span>Patient</label>
</span> 
<span class="oneChoice">
  <input type="radio" value="tfa_79" class="" id="tfa_791" name="tfa_78">
  <label class="label postField" id="tfa_791" for="tfa_791">
  <span class="input-radio-faux"></span>Patient</label>
</span>
```

OR

```css
.oneChoice {
  position:relative;
}
input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

input[type=radio] + label:before {
  content: "";
  border: 0.1em solid #000;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;  
  margin-right: 0.2em;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: transparent;
  transition: .2s;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

input[type=radio] + label:active:before {
  transform: scale(0);
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
  background-color: #662D91;
  border-color: #662D91;
  color: #fff;
}

input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  content:"";
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;

}


input[type=radio]:disabled + label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  border-color: #aaa;
}

input[type=radio]:checked:disabled + label:before {
  transform: scale(1);
  background-color: #bfb;
  border-color: #bfb;
}
```

```html
<span class="oneChoice">
  <input type="radio" value="tfa_79" class="" id="tfa_79" name="tfa_78">
  <label class="label postField" id="tfa_79" for="tfa_79">
  <span class="input-radio-faux"></span>Patient</label>
</span> 
<span class="oneChoice">
  <input type="radio" value="tfa_79" class="" id="tfa_791" name="tfa_78">
  <label class="label postField" id="tfa_791" for="tfa_791">
  <span class="input-radio-faux"></span>Patient</label>
</span>
```

Comment: i want radio Minal not checkbox thats my issue

Comment: It just looks like a checkbox but It's working like a radio button, what you want?

Comment: Yes it works like radio but can i get round shape instead of square please

Comment: Update my answer, change in border-radius, width and height

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?
A radio button that can choose only 1 option and has circle icon.

```css
.radio-btn {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-right: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  
}
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5;
  left: 12;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio-btn">Choice1
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="radio-btn">Choice2
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="radio-btn">Choice3
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```